# difference b/w **ptr and *ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

The basic knowledge i have about pointers is that they point to a memory location and that they can be used for changing and extracting the values stored at that address.
for eg.

```
int a=5;
int *b;
b=&a;
```

Now here b points to the memory location of a.

```
cout<<*b; //gives the output 5
cout<<b;  //outputs the address of a.
```

Basically for the purpose and passing the values by reference in functions and in data structures such as linked list and trees.

```
main()
{
  node *head=NULL;// A pointer head of type node structure
  add(&head,2); //adds the value to linked list
}

void add(node**head,int data)
{
  //adds value into node
}
```

Can any one tell me why the &head has been received as **head in the add() function.
Also, what difference would it have made had it been received as *head?

when i print the value of **head it gives me a compiler error.

Comment: Hints: For every type `T`, `T *` is a pointer to `T`. If `T` is `node *`, what will `T *` be?

Comment: Sometimes a simple comment solves everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

type of head is node*, when you get address of node* (&head), type of it is node**.

Difference between node** and node* is same as int* and int. One of them defines a pointer to other type.

add method gets a pointer because it might change the value of head. if *head  is NULL, it should create a new node and assign *head to address of this new node. if it inputted just node* head, assigning head = malloc(...) wouldn't work since c is pass by value and it just assigns the "head" defined within the function, not head in the main. but if gets the address of the head in the main, it can freely alter it by accessing it like *head = malloc(...)

head is a pointer so you can't really print its value (well, you can if you cast it but it wouldn't be anything meaningful). You probably need to cast it

Answer (score 0):

```
int *p; // p -> is a pointer to an int, *p -> integer contained in address pointed by p.
```

similarly

```
int **p2; // p2 -> a pointer to a pointer to an it, *p2 -> pointer to a int, **p2 int.
```

If you are confused, you can remember it as a covering rule. If you want to know what *p is, just cover *p ( we have int so it is an int ), if you to know what *p2 is, just cover it ( we have int * meaning it is a pointer to an int ).

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20818342/2805305

The question was about an error the op got, but in my answer I explain exactly what you need to know.